# Artifactory-Plugin won't deploy, because it thinks the build failed

Tags: artifactory, bamboo

I'm trying to use the Artifactory-Plugin for `bamboo` to deploy a `tar.gz` into artifactory. However, after the build went successful, the plugin won't even try to deploy and instead just writes

```
Build failed, not deploying to Artifactory.
```

I have no idea, why it would think, that the build failed. Does anyone else know this problem and has a suggestion on how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

As I just noticed, there was actually an error in my build before, which I didn't see, because it wasn't critical and was well hidden in the hundreds of lines of log. After getting rid of that error, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

[BAP-195](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/BAP-195) Was filed for this issue.

In my case Artifactory plugin fails to deploy even if build scripts has failonerror="false".